# JsonPath expression involving two root values

Tags: jsonpath, jayway

I have following JSON, I need to get the personEmailContact which has a matching emailID with emailupdaterequest.emailContact. I tried to write the expression like
*$.responsebody[?(@.personEmailContact.emailId ==$.emailupdaterequest.emailContact.emailId)]*
but this does not seem to work, I need to write an expression which can work without substitution. Can anyone help with any pointers

```
{
    "emailupdaterequest": {
        "emailContact": {
            "emailId": "admin@gmail.com",
            "contactName": "ADMIN EMAIL"
        }
    },
    "responsebody": [
        {
            "personEmailContact": {
                "emailId": "admin@gmail.com",
                "contactTypeCode": "P",
                "contactName": "Joe"
            }
        },
        {
            "personEmailContact": {
                "emailId": "nonadmin@gmail.com",
                "contactTypeCode": "P",
                "contactName": "john"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Use https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/ to test Jayway JsonPath expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the root selector `$` inside an expression.  This will allow you to compare values inside an array element to values elsewhere within the JSON:

```
$.responsebody[?(@.personEmailContact.emailId == $.emailupdaterequest.emailContact.emailId)]
```

Note the `$.emailupdaterequest.emailContact.emailId`.

`$` indicates the path is evaluated from the root of the JSON, whereas `@` indicates that the path is evaluated from the current item as the processor iterates over the array.

Comment: This does not work, when i evaluated the same https://jsonpath.com/ it shows jsonPath: $ is not defined: _$_v.personEmailContact.emailId == $.emailupdaterequest.emailContact.emailId

Comment: Well , I stand corrected, it seems https://jsonpath.com/ is not evaluating expression correctly. When i tried using com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath in java it worked. Thanks @gregsdennis

Comment: Yeah, not all implementations are the same.  We're working on a specification.

Comment: https://jsonpath.com/ uses [jsonpath-plus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath-plus)